# asp.NET jqueryUI autocomplete

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, jquery-ui

like described in the headline i got a little problem getting the jqueryUI autocomplete Widget to work.

It sounds silly but i`m hanging the whole day getting that thing solved, but i didn`t. I`ve developed a few years C# and now trying, since a month or so..., to develop with asp and jquery. Just for showing, I´ve searched the web and especially stackoverflow and tried a lot to getting it run.

Ok here`s the code.

**Definition TextBox:**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchbox"
                    style="float:left;padding:5px 1px 5px 1px;" runat="server" >
 </asp:TextBox>
```

**The AutoComplete Jquery Script Part:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtSearchbox').autocomplete( {
         source: function (request, response) {
                    //console.log(request.term);
             $.ajax
             ({
                 url: "AutoComplete.asmx/GetSearchInfo",
                 data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "' }",
                 dataType: "json",
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataFilter: function (data) {
                     //console.log(data.toString());
                     //alert(data.toString());
                     return data;
                 },
                 success: function (data) {
                     // console.log(data.d.toString());
                     response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                         // console.log(item.Isin)
                         // console.log(item.Name)
                         return
                         {
                             label: item.Name.toString()
                             value: item.Name.toString()
                         }
                     }));
                },
                 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert(textStatus);
                 }
             });
         },
         minLength: 2
         });
    });

</script>
```

**The AutoComplet.asmx:**

```
[WebMethod]
public List<SearchObject> GetSearchInfo(string prefixText) 
{
    var seo = new SearchObject();
    var getSeo = staticList.getSEOlist().Where(str => str.SearchString.ToLower().Contains(prefixText.ToLower()));

    return getSeo.ToList();
}
```

**For the sake of completeness, the CSS:**

```
    /*AutoComplete flyout */
.autocomplete_completionListElement
{
    margin:0px!important;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:windowtext;
    border:buttonshadow;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    cursor:'default';
    overflow:auto;
    height:200px;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:small;
    text-align:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }

/* AutoComplete highlighted item */
.autocomplete_highlightedListItem
{
    background-color:#ffff99 ;
    color:black;
    padding:0px;
    }

    /* AutoComplete item */
.autocomplete_listItem
{
    background-color:window;
    color:windowtext;
    padding:0px;
   }
```

If you need more, please tell me.

The debug lines are outcommented.

If i check the jquery part i get the data i want but it won't be displayed at the txtsearch.
And i didn't really understand how that AutoComplete jquerUI Method will display that List, but the coding should be correct.

Comment: What does the response from your web service method look like? (As in the JSON encoded data that is sent to the client)

Comment: {"d":[{"__type":"SearchObject","Nr1":"58155","nr2":"E58155","Name":"XX Name","SearchString":"58155 XX Name E58155"}]} - But that`s OK, it was a JavaScript Feature - look at the last Answer, with changing the code structrure a little bit, everything works, really wired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you could be a victim of a very nasty JavaScript feature called automatic semicolon insertion. The return statement in your success callback / jQuery map function is written wrong.

```
return
{
    label: item.Name.toString()
    value: item.Name.toString()
}
```

This should be a correct syntax:

```
return {
    label: item.Name.toString()
    value: item.Name.toString()
}
```

JavaScript compiler adds an automatic semicolon behind the return statement in the first case, causing it to return nothing / undefined.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion) has a very good overview of the rules for this behavior.

Comment: That`s really a very nasty & stinky Feature. That means if you try to get your Code into a nice looking structure(for me it looks good that way ; )  ) that won`t work. So after all searching around it works, Thank you very much Miroslav!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I have autocomplete running using asp.net, c# on .net 4. This is how i do it.

//   for .aspx page,

```
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="/PathToServiceHere/AutoComplete.svc" />            
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

// text box, I don't use server side text box here, but I don't see it being an issue for JQuery

```
  <input id="ModelBox" type="text" style="width: 158px;" />
```

// Jquery

```
     $(function () {
            $("#ModelBox").autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                delay: 0,
                cache: true,
                source: function (req, addToList) {

                    var popList = new GetAutoCompleteService.GetAutoComplete();
                    popList.GetModels(req.term, function (model) {

                        var listItems = [];
                        if (model.length > 0) {
                            for (var key = 0; key < model.length; key++) {
                                listItems.push(model[key].Model);
                            }
                        } else {
                            listItems.push("No Matching Model.");
                        }
                        addToList(listItems);
                    }, function onError() {
                    });
                }
            });

            $("#ModelBox").click(function () {
                // close if already visible
                if ($("#ModelBox").autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                    $("#ModelBox").autocomplete("close");
                    return;
                }

                // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                $(this).blur();

                // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                $("#ModelBox").autocomplete("search", "");
                $("#ModelBox").focus();
            });
        });
```

// AutoComplete.svc

```
  namespace autocomplete.Service
    {
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;

        using System.ServiceModel;
        using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

        using System.Data;

        [ServiceContract(Namespace = "GetAutoCompleteService")]
        [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
        public class GetAutoComplete
        {

            [OperationContract]
            public List<Models> GetModels(string model)
            {

               // Data access here to retrieve data for autocomplete box then convert to list

    // or however you get the data into list format
                List<Models> List = dataJustPulled.ToList(); 
                return List;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - Another interesting approach. I got it to work, the last answer did it, an absolute unnecessary JavaScript Feature causes that Errror.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Solved.**

It Works, with the help of Miroslav Popovic, i got the thing to work, it was that really useless JavaScript Feature 'automatic semicolon insertion'.

With a little changing the Code structure everything works fine.

Here`s the corrected part:

```
return{
       label: item.Name.toString(),
       value: item.Name.toString()
}
```

THX - To all that helped